# Bash: Separating a file by blank lines and assigning to a list

Tags: bash, list, awk

So i have a file for example

```
a

b
c

d
```

I'd like to make the list of the lines with data out of this. The empty line would be the seperator. So above file's list would be

```
First element = a 
Second element = b
c
Third element = d
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just for future references.  Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Replace blank lines with `,`, then remove newline characters:

```
cat <file> | sed 's/^$/, /' | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following awk would do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS=",";FS="\n";OFS=""}($1=$1)' file
```

This adds an extra `,` at the end. You can get rid of that in the following way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS=",";FS="\n";OFS=""}
     {$1=$1;s=s $0 ORS}END{sub(ORS"$","",s); print s}' file
```

But what happened now, by making this slight modification to eliminate the last `ORS` (i.e. comma), you have to store the full thing in memory. So you could then just do it more boring and less elegant by storing the full file in memory:

```
awk '{s=s $0}END{gsub(/\n\n/,",",s);gsub(/\n/,"",s); print s}' file
```

The following sed does exactly the same. Store the full file in memory and process it.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/,/g;s/\n//g' <file>
```

There is, however, a way to play it a bit more clever with awk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=OFS="";FS="\n"}{$1=$1; print (NR>1?",":"")$0}' file
```

Comment: The awk script adds a comma `,` after the last number.

Comment: @oliv, yes it does.

Comment: What if the file had Strings in it. I like the awk example, but it assumes numbers

Comment: @RF you will need to be more specific. Please update your question to show more information. Add an [mcve], that is, a representable input, an expected output and more importantly, what have you attempted yourself. I ask you this as I currently don't know what you mean with your comment as it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with that data.

With perl, you have a one-liner:

```
$ perl -00 -lnE 'say "element $. = $_"' file.txt
element 1 = a
element 2 = b
c
element 3 = d
```

But clearly you need to process the elements in some way, and I suspect Perl is not your cup of tea.

With bash you could do:

```
elements=()
n=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
     [[ $line ]] && elements[n]+="$line"$'\n' || ((n++))
done < file.txt
# strip the trailing newline from each element
elements=("${elements[@]/%$'\n'/}")
# and show what's in the array
declare -p elements
```

```
declare -a elements='([0]="a" [1]="b
c" [2]="d")'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print "Element " NR " = " $0}' file
Element 1 = a
Element 2 = b
c
Element 3 = d
```

If you really want to say `First Element` instead of `Element 1` then enjoy the exercise :-).